# How to transform an imbalanced attribute to make it more suitable for linear regression?

Tags: dataset, linear-regression

I'm new to data science but trying to get better

Here I have an attribute and plotting its histogram
[image: histogram]

From what I know so far such a distribution is imbalanced and my goal is to equalize things a little bit right?
Again from what I know, I have to transform this attribute to be more suitable for linear regression?

Is it obvious (to someone more experienced than me) which kind of transformation is applicable in this case?

*Note that this is an attribute and not my target, this is not what I am trying to predict. This is one of the attributes to be used for predicting*

Comment: You could try a logarithmic transformation.

Comment: Because your data's distribution looks quasi exponential, and the logarithm is its inverse. Gerenuk  explained the options well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple options and you may choose the best by seeing the performance.

First one is to use a guess. For positive-only values the log-transform is a hot candidate to make sense (maybe correct for small values here to avoid exceedingly large negative transformed values).

Log-transform is natural if percentage increases have a particular real-world meaning. This is often the case for financial data. Why is log a hot candidate? You probably know that when there are addititve real world effects, the normal distribution often appears. Now, when you have multiplicative effects, you get the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution .

Other common transformations are power transforms, where you take some power of the values. I don't think there are many more which are very common. Theoretically, your perfect transform would make the noise on the linear regression Gaussian, but no-one can tell what that would be and most likely reality isn't perfectly linear anyway.

A transform is more interesting when the transformed values follow a Gaussian distribution. But that is just a guess and in the end only final performance evaluation can tell more.

For a second option, be aware that you can force the transformed values to be any distribution you want. For example, if you take ranks of the values you get a uniform transformed distribution. You could even force it to be a Gaussian by a suitable mapping. However, in your case, this will lose the interesting bump on the right.

I think these are the most common options. *In data science, nothing is ever obvious and most of the time you can only decide by performance evaluation (cross-validation with the whole model)*.

Conclusion:

Set up a performance test (cross-validation; not on final test set though if you like a fair, final evaluation) and try all of the following

- Try untransformed. It might already be what has most information.
- Try log-transform (while adding a small offset if you have some very small values)
- Try power-transform if you like

Answer (score 0):

I think what might help you given your problem is Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique for Regression (SMOTER). There is some research on this topic. However, it remains less explored than its classification counterpart, as you have likely encountered.

I might suggest the paper cited below (and the conference it was presented at http://proceedings.mlr.press/v74/) depending on how interested you are in understanding it from a research perspective. I really appreciated the introduction of Gaussian noise in generating the synthetic observations.

If you're more interested in a practical solution, the first author has an R implementation available on her Github page. https://github.com/paobranco/SMOGN-LIDTA17

If Python is more of your persuasion, I recently released an entirely Pythonic implementation of the SMOGN algorithm that is now available and currently being unit tested. https://github.com/nickkunz/smogn

Branco, P., Torgo, L., Ribeiro, R. (2017). "SMOGN: A Pre-Processing Approach for Imbalanced Regression". Proceedings of Machine Learning Research, 74:36-50.http://proceedings.mlr.press/v74/branco17a/branco17a.pdf.